# window builder pro in eclipse mars 4.50

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I recently tried to install Window Builder pro in eclipse Mars 4.5.0, first time I got errors installing, but it finally installed. But its not working correctly. It shows a blank page when I try to open the palette or structures. What maybe the issue? Any advice on how I can make it work? Thank you.

Comment: try with fresh eclipse and get window builder installed.

Comment: Which errors did you get? And could you take a look into `installed software` and check if the windowbuilder got installed completly or is missing some files?